# What is NON-HLOS.bin? For what purpose it is been made?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, 7.0-nougat

In new builds I have notice that file but i don't know for what it is used while installing an OS.
Someone answer please!
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's the modem/baseband firmware (or to be precise, often a part of it). Not every build would update it, but major builds often do contain tweaks to it.

Comment: So non-high-level operating system, I guess?